# SSRS 2014 database setup - error "Using other editions of SQL Server for report data sources..." is not supported

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am setting up a new SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Reporting Services instance on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server.

In Reporting Services Configuration Manager, when I select the SQL Server instance where I want to setup a new report database, the error message below is shown:

The feature: "Using other editions of SQL Server for report data sources and/or the report server database" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

Error: 
[image]

The SQL Server instance where I intend to setup the report database runs SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition build 12.0.4422 (which is displayed in Management Studio and @@version) and the SQL Server instance where I am configuring Reporting Services runs also MSQL 2014 build 12.0.4422 as displayed in Reporting Services Configuration Management - **but Enterprise Edition** (I've just installed SQL Server Cumulative Update 2 from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3075950).

If I select an instance which runs SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition build 10.50.4260 instead, the error is not shown and the setup proceeds correctly - but unfortunately this is not the instance where the report database should be.

What am I missing here? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Cristhian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is correct.  The reporting services database is supported on a wide range of versions.

You are not allowed to use a production reporting services against a developer version database.  (Why would you want to!).  You can either use a developer edition of reporting services, or an enterprise database.

Comment: Hm.  My situation might be a little different (and I think this would help cneumann)  I initially installed SQL Express.  I was not able to get the Report Server working correctly.  Research indicated that the Full Version of SQL 2016 would enable me to use all features in the Report Server.  I have now both installations, SQL Express, and the full SQL 2016.  I assumed that the SSRS and the RS Configuration Manager would default now to the full version.  Apparently not.  I am getting the error above.  Help?

Comment: You may have more than one copy of the Reportnig Service Configuration manager.  This is certainly true for difference versions, e.g. Enterprise 2014 and Enterprise 2016.  I'm not clear on which version of Express you are using.   If its the same version but different editions, I'd expect you to have a choice which instance to connect to.