# SSMS can't connect to SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, installation, ssms, ssms-2017

I'm learning the SQL server suite and just installed the Developer Edition. I included in my features the Integration and Analysis Services. As for the Reporting ones, I went back online (as indicated) and download/installed it.

Now, in my Start Menu / Microsoft SQL Server, I have the Reporting Services Configuration Manager. I click on it, a window pops asking me to indicate a server name and connect, which I do. At this point, everything seems to work and all is great and in the Current Report Server box, the status displays "active".

BUT! When I go into SQL Server Configuration Manager, it's not displayed.[image]

So I checked the Reporting Services Configuration Manager again in case if something changed there: negative, all the same and the status is still active. 
If I try to connect to it in SQL Server Management Studio, the "Reporting Services" server type appears and allows me to choose my server:
[image]

It doesn't work as well. 
[image]

I'm starting to think I need to delete the entire SQL Server thing and go through it again, but does any1 have any better solutions? (if additionnal screenshots are needed, please let me know and I'll edit).

Thanks to all!

**Edit**

Thanks to DeanOC's answer below, I was able to connect, however, the SQL Server Configuration Manager still doesn't display the Reporting Service server and, in SSMS, when I click on any of the three possible crosshairs I get the following error:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I found the following instructions https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/956179/error-message-when-you-click-the-databases-node-in-sql-server-manageme

But my SSMS crashes every time I right click on the column... <(-_-")>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victory! I found the issue. Firstly, I haven't completed the setup... So in the "Report Server Configuration Manager", I have omitted the "Database" tab and the setup it entails.

Although, at this point, I was able to access the Report Manager URL through my browser, I was still unable to connect to the "Reporting Services" through SSMS. And here's how I solved it:

I noticed that my Virtual Directory name in "Web Services URL" as well as "Web Portal URL" were identical, so assuming that this was possibly a cause for the error I changed them to different names: one was remained "SSRS", the other was changed to "reports". Bang!

Comment: Can you explain the process a little more eloborately?

Answer (score 9):

In SSMS, when connecting to Reporting Services you have to specify the reporting services URL, not the name of the server hosting reporting services.

So in the 'Server name' box you need to type

http://MAX-PC/reportserver

Tip: if you are running SSMS on the server that is hosting reporting services, you can also use

http://localhost/reportserver

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks a lot! As I went thru the "Reporting Services Configuration Manager", I found the url that worked contained the port number after the PC name field. So, http://MAX-PC:80/reportserver.
But the SQL Server Configuration Manager still doesn't display it and I get an error once I connect to it and click on any crosshair. I posted the printscreen above. Would you have any other suggestions plz?

Comment: I can't offer you any more advice other than to reinstall reporting services. You should be able to use the SQL Server installer to just uninstall that component rather than remove SQL Server entirely. Although, to be honest I would personally nuke the lot and start from scratch, especially since you haven't started using it yet.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't need to specify port 80 in the URL, as port 80 is the default for the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Understood! Great, thanks for clearing it up. To avoid future issues and ensure that I start with a proper initial setup, I'll nuke the lot as u formulated it =') Have a good one!

Comment: @DeanOC I am trying to use the SSRS but while doing configuration getting an error:--> `The feature: 'Using other editions of SQL Server for report data sources and/or the report server database is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale perhaps this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998070/ssrs-2014-database-setup-error-using-other-editions-of-sql-server-for-report

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one remote server on which SSRS is properly configured. Can I use that server to deploy my locally created reports? I m new to this

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I don't see why you couldn't deploy your locally created reports to the remote server. You will need to create a datasource on the remote server to point to a valid database, and modify the deployed report to use that datasource.

Comment: It is wonderful that it solve my problem. And I don't know why I always tied the `localhost/ssrs` before !